# How to check connect 4 for horizontal wins

Tags: python

*I am trying to find code to check if four or more 1's, or 2's are next to each other in the 2d list and then return my win function as true

Here is the code below:

```
# Connect Four

# 2d list
numRows = 6
numCols = 7
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ]


def printBoard():
    for rows in range(0, numRows):
        for cols in range(0, numCols):
            print(board[rows][cols], end=' ')
        print(" ")


def fillIn(col, player):
    col = col - 1
    for rows in range(numRows - 1, -1, -1):
        if board[rows][col] == 0:
            print("Legal Move")
            board[rows][col] = player
            break


def win():
    if horizWin() or vertWin() or diagWin():
        return True
    return False


def horizWin():
    return False


def vertWin():
    return False


def diagWin():
    pass


player = 1

while not win():
    col = int(input("Please Select A Colum 1-7: "))

    fillIn(col, player)
    printBoard()
    if player == 1:
        player = 2
    else:
        player = 1
```

I was following a tutorial and it abruptly stopped. So any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

I added some debug print statements so you understand better what is happening step by step. Dissable the prints when you are comfortable on how the code works

```
def horizWin():
    # loop over each row in the board
    for row in board:
        print (f"Current row: {row}")
        # take a window of size 4 and slide it over the row.
        # you need to iterate from 0 to len(row)-windowsize+1
        for i in range(len(row)-4+1):
            window = row[i:i+4]
            print(f"    Current window: {window}")
            # check if all elements in the row are 1s or 2s
            # all elements are the same if the number of elements 
            # equal to the first one is the size of the window.
            # you also need to check that this element is 1 or 2 
            if window.count(window[0]) == 4 and window[0] in (1,2):
                print(f"    This window has a winning position for player {window[0]}")
                return True
    print("No winning positions found in the board")
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks this solution worked!

But since I want to understand the solution could you explain the "Window = row[i:i+4] line and the if windows.count(window[0]) == len(window) and window[0] in [1,2]?

Comment: I tried to explain it in the comments. Still if you feel that you don't understand the code try to understand the logic of sliding a window of size 4 over the current row and implement it yourself the way you feel more comfortable. You can create auxiliary functions like `def areAllElementsTheSame(myList):` if this makes the code easier for you